# Nexus 7 (2013) and Win 7 64 - cannot install USB driver despite checking many forums and online resources

Tags: android, windows, driver, windows-7-x64, nexus-7

I'm trying to set up my Nexus 7 (2013) for debugging, but I am getting stuck at the step where you install the USB driver.  Here's what I've tried so far:

Steps taken:

1. Turned on debugging mode on Nexus 7 (2013)
2. Connected device to PC
3. Downloaded Google USB Driver at http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html (and unpacked it)
4. Opened Computer Management and tried to update drivers on Nexus 7 device
5. Directed the driver update wizard to the unpacked usb_driver folder with Include Subfolders checked (not the zip file nor the amd64 and i386 folders inside), but I get the message: "Windows could not find driver software for your device."
6. Installed Google USB Driver with Android SDK Manager
7. Used update driver wizard with path to usb_driver folder from SDK manager, same result.
8. Tried using "Let me pick from a list of device drivers" option on update driver wizard.
9. Picked "Android USB Devices", then clicked "Have Disk" button
10. Pointed to android_winusb.inf inside usb_driver folder, got message: "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device. If the folder contains a driver, make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems."

I'm pretty much at my wit's end (I usually try to find answers myself or from other posts online, but this one's got me stumped pretty hard.)  Can anyone help?

Comment: in console what u are getting can you tell me

Comment: console? What do you mean?

Answer (score 22):

Don´t use USB3.0 ports ... try it on a usb 2.0 port

Also try to change transfer mode, like suggested here:
https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49662

Comment: Ahhh, that second one did it, changing the transfer mode.  Thanks!

Comment: Then pls accept it as the answer to your question ;) Thank you

Comment: Changing the transfer mode to camera did it also for me (Nexus 7 2013)... unbelievable, after more than a hour trying all different stuff something so simple did the job...

Comment: None of this worked for me. Tried on USB 2.0 ports, USB2+eSATA combined port, USB2+power, USB 3.0, none works. Error is that the "driver" (which is actually a usermode DLL) fails to start.

Answer (score 14):

cracked it after 2 hours...

1. download this usb driver:
   http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePAD/nexus7/usb_driver_r06_windows.zip

2.go to the device manager , right click the nexus device and choose properties,
 choose "hardware" and then choose update your driver , choose manualy and pick the folder 
you opend the zip file to and press apply.

3.open your setting in nexus . go to : "about the device" , at to the bottom of the page and press it strong text7 times .

4.open the developers menu and enable debug with usb.

5.finally press storage from the setting menu and click the menu that apears at the top left corner.
press the connect usb to the computer, choose the second option (PTP).

one more thing: if that doesn't work restart your computer

that should do the trick , they couldn't make it more simple than that...

Comment: Enabling PTP was the missing vital step I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Enabling PTP lets you install the driver, but the phone will again not get detected in the MTP mode. Can you debug in the PTP mode?

Comment: I've gone through all these steps with no success. They could make this a lot simpler.

Comment: thank you a lot! worked fine for my nexus 7 after android 5 update :) (URL for driver and settings for PTP were the key)

Answer (score 12):

You can do this go to Settings > Storage, clicking on the setting menu icon in the top right hand corner and selecting "USB computer connection". I then changed the storage mode to "Camera (PTP)". Done try re installing the driver from device manager.

Comment: Crazy, but you are right.  Once I changed the transfer mode on my device, my computer was able to recognize the files as drivers, were previously it didn't.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The universal adb driver installer worked for me. I went from an HTC to a Samsung to a LG Nexus. The drivers are all over the place for me.

http://adbdriver.com/

Answer (score 1):

I also got this problem and found quite simple solution. 
I have Samsung adb driver installed on my system. I tried "Update driver" -> "Let me pick" -> "Already installed drivers" ->  Samsung adb driver. That worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the device, sometimes you are getting "The folder you specified doesn't contain a compatible software" error because the first interface isn't actually the ADB interface.

Try installing it as a generic "USB composite device" instead (from the 'pick from a list' driver install option); once the standard composite driver installs it will allow Windows to communicate with the device and detect the associated ADB driver interface and install it properly.

Comment: using Google USB Driver and selecting other\all devices\have disk\Android Composite ADB Interface works. pretty crazy that google usb drivers does not include HWIDs for their own devices.

Answer (score 0):

SkipSoft.net has some great toolkits.  I ran into a similar problem with my Galaxy Nexus.... Ran the corresponding toolkit, which configured my system and downloaded the correct drivers.  I then went into Windows Hardware manager after connecting the phone... Windows reported the exclamation that it couldn't find the device driver, so I ran update, and gave it the drivers directory the toolkit had created... and everything started working great.  Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Asus Nexus 7 on my Windows 7 64 bits computer for development purposes :

I tried to install the driver for the nexus 7 manually like explained in the official tutorial of Asus

**Unfortunately, I had an error, Windows couldn't recognize the driver.**

I tried to change the USB connection mode to PTP or MTP by going in the storage menu and clicking on the top right menu . In both cases, windows recognize the devices **but it still didn't work in debugging mode.**

**The only way it worked** for me is by installing :  [adb universal installer](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) . I scanned it before clicking on the executable, it seems to be fine.