# android 2013 nexus 7 and windows 8.1 x-64 drivers

Tags: android, usb, driver, nexus-7

i have made drivers work for the 2012 nexus 7, and a few other android devces.

i just got 6 2013 nexus 7's and can not seem to get the drivers installed. i upgraded the software to 6.0.1.

but i am unable to get to the screen shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888606/which-version-of-adb-interface-for-android-nexus-7-2013).

adb does not find any devices. in ptp mode, windows finds most of these and assigns a usb driver 6.3.9600.17415 dated 2006. trying update the driver to add a more specific driver fails because windows does not know it's a phone. using have disk fails when opening the .inf file like these: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469576/nexus-7-2013-and-win-7-64-cannot-install-usb-driver-despite-checking-many-fo), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771892/unable-to-install-the-android-usb-driver-on-windows-7), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469576/nexus-7-2013-and-win-7-64-cannot-install-usb-driver-despite-checking-many-fo).

in charging mode, windows device manager thinks it's a google nexus adb  interface, but does not show and phone options. have disk fails also.

so adb devices fails.

this used to work somehow, but i deleted some of the drivers.

plugging in a 2012 nexus 7 shows up as an android composite adb interface and he shows up in adb list-devices.

does anyone know a way out of this trap?

edit [this](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html) may be part of the problem. tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmw86KplqmU) to disable driver signature verification, but no joy.

trying shazar's idea required an uninstall (repair failed) of the clockwork driver, so some (5/6) of the devices are using the clockwork driver version 7.0.0.4 8/27/2012 when the nexus is in ptp mode. another is not recognized (no connection info when swiped down from the top).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing this [Universal ADB Driver](http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi) by Koushik Dutta.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Official.

Update to Android studio 2.3.3 causes not recognizing my Nexus 7, 2012. The pre-Installed USB driver was tampered. It was working before.

I have fixed it by,

1. Go to https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html
2. Download the Driver zip file and update the driver software at PC's Device Manager-->Portable devices-->Update driver software--> < browse and select the downloaded USB driver path >